# How to populate check boxes from Mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkboxlist, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to retrieve data to check-box list when user selected an option from a drop-down list. So, the main categories are loaded in a drop-down list and subcategories are suppose to be loaded in a list of check-boxes. Right now, I sorted out to populate data to another drop-down list. here is my code:

**JQuery Code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader" style="position:inline;"><img src="device manager/img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('user manager/loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
  <tr>
    <?php 
    include('config.php'); 
    $query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblclient") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
    ?>
     <form method="get">
     <tr>
        <td><label>Client</label></td>

        <td>
            <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Client</option>
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['clientId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clientName']; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
        <br/><br/>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Branch</label></td>

        <td>
            <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" multiple>
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Branch</option>
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     </form>
```

**Loading subcategory list PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT B.*, C.* FROM tblbranch B INNER JOIN tblclientbranch CB on CB.branchId = B.branchId INNER JOIN tblclient C ON CB.clientId = C.clientId WHERE C.clientId = {$parent_cat}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[branchId]'>$row[branchName]</option>";
}

?>
```

Does anyone know how to populate subcategories to a list of check-boxes?

Any solution would be great.
Thanks for reading my long code!

Comment: Do you need something like this: https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="branch" value="$row[branchid]">$row[branchname]<br>
```

Comment: And remove the `<select>` and give its `id` to surrounding `<td>` element.